# How do I use SQL for localization rather than .resx files?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2012

I have been trying to get my head around this but essentially I want to hold details of all objects in the database and when the page loads it will retrieve the correct text for the object from the database for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep all your dictionaries in SQL and retrieve them before your visual controls are drown. 
You need a dictionary of you "base" spelling say in English as a key and values for different languages you would like to use.

Comment: Yes but I am looking for some technical information on how to retrieve and set the values.